# lighthouse-php query custom result

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I am getting no answer when I add some custom fields to graphQL resolver

My query is:

```php
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext;

class ComplexQuery
{
    public function __invoke($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo)
    {
        return [ 'complexResult'=> 33]
        // I tried this but I had the same result
        // return (object) [ 'complexResult'=> 33]
    }
}
```

And in queries, I defined the next schema:

```
type Query {
  complexQuery: complexTypeQuery
}

type complexTypeQuery {
  complexResult: Int
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the semicolon in the `type complexTypeQuery: {` line.

Update:
Also you arn't specifying the field resolver in the query definition.

```
type Query {
  complexQuery: complexTypeQuery @field(resolver: "ComplexQuery")
}
```

Comment: Also you arn't specifying which field resolver to use in your query definition